# How to update Firefox WebExtensions deployed with Firefox in an enterprise environment?

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

I am distributing Firefox ESR in an enterprise environment, including a homemade WebExtension in the distribution\extension directory as explained in https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/deploying-firefox-with-extensions

This instance of Firefox is installed to be used for a particular set of applications and is not intended to be used as the user's main browser. It is launched through a cmd script with a specific profile, for instance :

Firefox\browser\firefox.exe -profile myParticularProfile

Starting Firefox this way creates the profile if not already present, and the profile will not be visible in the profile manager.

Everything is fine after initial installation : every new profile of every user will get the extension copied to the extensions directory of its profile, and the extension is activated.

**However, I need to be able to update the extension without reinstalling Firefox. The problem is, the updated extension does not get copied to existing profiles.**

The documentation says that the extensions will be updated when Firefox is updated, but I need to be able to update the extension without updating/reinstalling Firefox.

- Clearing the "extensions" folder in the profile does not solve the problem (the extension does not come back with the update version as I hoped)
- I also tried clearing various cache directories without success

I hope I will not need to write a command script to update the extensions myself since I am not certain I will be able to easily locate and modify every user's profiles.

Maybe suggesting to firefox that it has been updated (even if it is not true) would do the trick, but I do not know if this is possible.

Any ideas ?